# Getting a simultaneous first $6$ with two dice

Tags: probability, random-variables, dice

**What's the probability that two players that each throw a normal dice get their first six at the same time ?**

---

Let $X_k,Y_k$ denote the numbers obtained with the first ($X$) and second ($Y$) dice at the $k$th try.

I'm having a hard time finding how to solve the problem. Could someone post an answer using random variables, with a detailed method, with the result ? That would really help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:  What is the chance they both get a six on the first roll?  In that case you succeed.  What is the chance exactly one of them gets a six on the first roll?  In that case you fail.  Otherwise, you are back where you started.  Scale the first two up to sum to $1$ and you are there.

Comment: I get $\displaystyle P=\frac{1}{36}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{2k}=\frac{1}{11}$, is that correct ?

Comment: I only asked about the first roll.  Later we can sum a series if we insist, but don't have to.  Random variables will only complicate the problem as well.

Comment: Oh, I was only asking for Random Variables because that was the chapter we were in when we were given that exercise. Still, is my probability (for the overall problem) correct ?

Comment: Ha I like that. I had set up a sequence of $\frac{1}{36}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty{(\frac{25}{36})^i(\frac{1}{36}})$ not realizing that you can just scale $\frac{1}{36}$ and $\frac{10}{36}$.  Nice.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but could you please tell me whether my answer is good or not ? By using simulations I get that $P\sim0.09264$, which doesn't match my $1/11$

Comment: Using the Law of Total Probability and conditioning on the first roll, I obtain 1/11, no series summation needed. Your simulation is pretty close. You can't expect high accuracy.

Comment: Yes, $1/11 \approx 0.0909$ is correct.  Either your simulation is just a bit of a fluctuation, or it is off somehow.